# External Full HD monitor and Virtual Desktop Size

Tags: xorg, ati, multiple-monitors

I have two FullHD monitors attached to my ATI graphics card [2]. The resolution of both of them is detected properly without any modifications to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I can run both of them in clone mode. However, when I try to run them next to each other, I got the following error: `The selected configuration for displays could not be applied`. If tried to fix this according to [1]. My `xorg.conf` now looks like this:

```
Section "Module"                                                                
        Load    "glx"                                                           
EndSection                                                                      

Section "Screen"                                                                
        Identifier      "Default Screen"                                        
        DefaultDepth    24                                                      
        SubSection "Display"   
              # The 1088 is the smallest multiple of 32 >= 1088
              # see manpages                                               
              Virtual 1920 1088                                               
        EndSubSection                                                         
EndSection
```

This does not seem to be parsed properly. After restarting X, I cannot set resolutions beyond 1600 or so any more. `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` gives:

```
[    15.676] (II) fglrx(0): Not using mode "1920x1080" (width too large for virtual size)
[    15.676] (II) fglrx(0): Not using mode "1680x1050" (width too large for virtual size)
```

Are my modifications syntactically incorrect? According to the `man` page, it should be fine. Any ideas?

OS: Ubuntu 11.10 64bit

[1] https://askubuntu.com/a/75546/5023
[2] 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Juniper [Radeon HD 5700 Series]

Answer (score 2):

if you want both screens next to each other your virtual size must be at least

<strike>Virtual 3840 1080</strike>

EDIT:

It seems like you need to extend the height too, so using

```
Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"                                        
        DefaultDepth    24                                                      
        SubSection "Display"
              Virtual 3840 3840                                               
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

as xorg.conf works for me

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` ? Your Screen section looks correct, what does your Monitor section look like?

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Monitor1" 
    HorizSync   28-110 
    VertRefresh 43-90 
    Modeline "1920x1200" 162 1920 1984 2176 2480 1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Monitor2" 
    HorizSync   28-110 
    VertRefresh 43-90 
    Modeline "1920x1200" 162 1920 1984 2176 2480 1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync
EndSection
```

If checking your Monitor sections doesn't fix your issue, my next step would be to remove some of your GUI based settings files.

> ~/.dt
>
> ~/.dtprofile