# xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1680x1680 (desired size 3360x1050)

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, xrandr

When executing this list of commands:

```
xrandr --output DFP3 --mode 1680x1050 --rate 60
xrandr --output CRT1 --mode 1680x1050 --rate 59
xrandr --output DFP3 --left-of CRT1 (error here)
xrandr --output CRT1 --primary
```

I have this output:

> xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1680x1680 (desired size 3360x1050)

I looked up and they recommended me to add a line in `xorg.conf` adding `Virtual 3360x1050` to the `Display` subsection. I added it and made a reboot but I have the same error. Here is my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Virtual 3360 1050
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: **This seems to be your monitor sized bigger.** **Do you have more information about where you installed it?** **on** Windows 7, XP, or Vista **using** Wubi, CD (burned), Virtual PC/VMware/VM Workstation, or Ubuntu Installer CD (Orignal) **Please answer so we can identify your problems. Don't forget the specs of your Computer so we can identify if there's incompatible to install Ubuntu.**

Comment: It is a Xubuntu install, using it as my main OS. And the size of the display is OK and has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and discovered that I had to extend the height as well as the width to make it work (thanks to ThomasKl's edit to his answer for this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111276)).

Try

```
Virtual 3360 3360
```

in the Display subsection.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Check if you have `xorg.conf` file in `/etc/X11`. If yes, go to step 3. Otherwise go to step 2.

Step 2: Create `xorg.conf`:

1. Switch to console mode: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. Kill the X server: `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. Generate new xorg.conf file: `sudo X -configure`

This will create `xorg.conf.new` in your current directory.

4. Rename and move: `sudo mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
5. Return to GUI: `sudo start lightdm`

Step 3: Open `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and add `Virtual 3200 1080` under subsection `Display`

1. `vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
2. Add `Virtual 3200 1080` to ALL `SubSection "Display"`

FOR ALL SCREEN if you have more than one `"Display"` Subsection and more than 1 screen (replace 3200 1080 with your desired screen resolution)

For example:

```
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen1"
Device     "Card1"
Monitor    "Monitor1"
SubSection "Display"
Viewport   0 0
Depth     1
Virtual 3200 1080
EndSubSection
EndSection
Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen2"
Device     "Card1"
Monitor    "Monitor1"
SubSection "Display"
Viewport   0 0
Depth     1
Virtual 3200 1080
EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Step 4. Restart your computer/laptop

Step 5. Create a script (`vi /etc/X11/dual_monitor.sh`) and include following

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --mode 1280x1024 
xrandr --output DVI-1 --mode 1920x1080 
xrandr --output DVI-0 --auto --right-of DVI-1 --pos 1920x0
```

Change the file permission

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/X11/dual_monitor.sh
```

(note: my screen1 is DVI-1 and screen2 is DVI-0, and replace resolution as per need)
Step 6. Execute the script and see if it works. (/etc/X11/dual_monirot.sh)

Step 7. If the script works, include the script to Auto Start

**Menu > Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart**

Add

- Name: Dual Monitor Xfce
- Description: Dual Monitor Xfce
- Command: `/etc/X11/dual_monitor.sh`

Step 8. Restart and enjoy

Step 9. Redo step 7 for all users logged in as the user