# Ubuntu 18.04 Xorg server error

Tags: 18.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, 4k-monitor, hdpi

I am trying to configure my new laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 (HP Spectre X360 late 2018 version). In particular, I would like to have per-monitor HiDPI scaling for my 4k laptop screen and my ultra-wide, non-HiDPI external monitor.

I was following this guide https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Side_display , that suggests to use `xrandr` for this purpose. However, when I run the suggested command, I get an error:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --auto --output DP-1 --auto --scale 2x2 --right-of eDP-1
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 8192x8192 (desired size 10720x2880)
```

Fair enough, let's change that. I then discovered that to do that I need to change the virtual screen setting in my `xorg.conf`, as specified here [xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1680x1680 (desired size 3360x1050)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303072/xrandr-screen-cannot-be-larger-than-1680x1680-desired-size-3360x1050) .

However, I am unable to create an `xorg.conf` at all. I tried multiple things:

1. Login to a `tty5` session, type `sudo service gdm3 stop` and then `sudo X -configure` gives me the following error: `Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running`, which doesn't make any sense since X should not be running at that point.
2. Enter ubuntu in Recovery mode and type `sudo X -configure` gives me instead another one : `modprobe: FATAL: Module fbcon not found in directory /lib/modules/$kernel
   intel: waited 2020 ms for i915.ko driver to load
   Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
   Configuration failed. (EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.`

At this point, I do not know what to do. Any suggestions?